# Julia "no method matching supports_default_copy_to(::GLPK.Optimizer, ::Bool)" declaring Model

Tags: julia, glpk, julia-jump

I am new to Julia and tried to run the first example script in the [Second Edition of Julia Programming for Operations Research](https://www.chkwon.net/julia/book/juliabook2-preview.pdf), but the first two lines:

```
using JuMP, GLPK
m = Model(with_optimizer(GLPK.Optimizer))
```

throw the following error:

```
julia> m = Model(with_optimizer(GLPK.Optimizer))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching supports_default_copy_to(::GLPK.Optimizer, ::Bool)
Closest candidates are:
  supports_default_copy_to(::MathOptInterface.Utilities.AbstractModel, ::Bool) at /home/mepstein/.julia/packages/MathOptInterface/C1XBe/src/Utilities/model.jl:693
  supports_default_copy_to(::MathOptInterface.Utilities.MockOptimizer, ::Bool) at /home/mepstein/.julia/packages/MathOptInterface/C1XBe/src/Utilities/mockoptimizer.jl:521
  supports_default_copy_to(::MathOptInterface.Utilities.CachingOptimizer, ::Bool) at /home/mepstein/.julia/packages/MathOptInterface/C1XBe/src/Utilities/cachingoptimizer.jl:165
```

In case it's relevant, `using JuMP, GLPK` threw the following `warning`:

```
┌ Warning: Replacing module MathOptInterface
└ @ Base loading.jl:942
```

And my versions are:

```
Julia: 1.3.1 (latest stable)
  "GLPK" => v"0.12.0"
  "JuMP" => v"0.20.1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by the book author at https://github.com/chkwon/jpor_codes/issues/4

Running `] up` from the `julia` interpreter upgraded GLPK to 12.1 from 12.0. Interesting because I had just installed GLPK in the first place only a couple hours ago. In fact I'm not even sure I 'upgraded' the installed version; from the log it looks like `] up` made certain config files consistent with the version that was already installed?

```
julia>
(v1.3) pkg>  up
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
 Resolving package versions...
 Installed GLPK ─ v0.12.1
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.3/Project.toml`
  [60bf3e95] ↑ GLPK v0.12.0 ⇒ v0.12.1
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.3/Manifest.toml`
  [60bf3e95] ↑ GLPK v0.12.0 ⇒ v0.12.1
  Building GLPK → `~/.julia/packages/GLPK/HjJiX/deps/build.log`
```

In any case, the code in the question above now works and gives the following output:

````
julia> using JuMP, GLPK

julia> m = Model(with_optimizer(GLPK.Optimizer))
A JuMP Model
Feasibility problem with:
Variables: 0
Model mode: AUTOMATIC
CachingOptimizer state: EMPTY_OPTIMIZER
Solver name: GLPK```
````